# How to migrate SharePoint hosted app from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, migration, sharepoint-hosted-app

How to migrate a SharePoint hosted app from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online?

Do that require the code of app to be rewritten or can we simply download and upload the app file to SharePoint online app catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you don't have to change anything. Just upload and that's it.
However there are a few things to check:

- does your app use any external APIs. If yes, probably you should change APIs CORS configuration to accept requests from new urls
- do you use any undocumented features or "hacks" in your code? Those hacks might not work in Online
- any code which uses SharePoint DOM manipulation or css selectors which modify SharePoint UI - it might be broken in Online, because markup in Online is slightly different